# Django custom locale directory

Tags: django, internationalization, locale

I'm developing a project with two different sites, divided by 
language. Maybe I was terribly wrong, but now my directory structure 
looks like:

```
/ruapp/settings.py # SITE_ID = 1 
/ruapp/manage.py 
/enapp/settings.py # SITE_ID = 2 
/enapp/manage.py 
/common/urls.py 
/common/ # almost every other file 
/common/templates/ # templates with {% trans %} 
/locale/ # with locales ru-ru and en-us, generated by calling 
makemessages from the root of all this structure
```

How to tell django about the locale? It does not seem like it will 
find the /locale/ folder by itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, python-gettext can't use different folder, so... Use Symlinks, Luke!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your directory structure for localization files look like that:

```
locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo 
locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
```

If you name them something else, or put them elsewhere, it probably won't work.

You also need to pust aproperiate l18n information in your settings file. `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'` in one, and `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'` in the other.

**Edit:** Have you created two separate *apps* or two separate *project*? Apps usually don't have their own settings.py and manage.py...

You can have one project that have multiple settings files and runs multiple websites. It would be much more django-ish (and much easier to deal with) for your directory structure to look like this:

```
/settings_ru.py # SITE_ID = 1 
/settings_en.py # SITE_ID = 2 
/manage.py # use --settings option to distinguish between settings files.
/urls.py 
/templates/ # templates with {% trans %} 
/locale/ # locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo and locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo 
(+ other common code, inside their respective apps)
```